# What happens when we take a timediff between timestamp and datetime

Tags: mysql, timestamp, innodb

Say I have following table in mysql (5.5+):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `y_time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My x_time is a `timestamp`, and y_time is a `datetime` column

I want to understand that what happens when I do `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, x_time, y_time)`

Does `x_time` gets converted to `datetime` and then the difference is calculated? or it happens vice-versa? Mysql manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) says: One expression may be a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary.

My assumption is that both the columns `x_time` and `y_time` has to been of one datatype to calculate TIMESTAMPDIFF, and if it is not already then mysql has to do it internally. Am I wrong here?

Also, if it has to convert one of the column to match the another column's datatype, then how the performance will matter for the following query? Will it do the datatype conversion for 5000 rows? And how time consuming process is this?

```
SELECT * from test WHERE `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, x_time, y_time)` LIMIT 100000, 5000
```

Comment: Could you devise an experiment to answer this?

Comment: @Strawberry: How? can you throw some light please?

Comment: Everything you asked about can be answered by yourself if you just run some SQL statements and read MySQL docs about `TIMESTAMPDIFF`. As for time consumption, how can anyone tell if we don't have access to the hardware? How fast will your code run on my smartphone? How fast will your code run on my home PC or my laptop?

Comment: @N.B.: Yeah I ran few statements.. but what I am not able to find is that whether it converting datatype of any column or not? How can find that by just running these queries?